# Reading COM Port Data in C++

Tags: c++, c

i have a device which is stethoscope digital machine, so i attach that machine with PC and get that machine data using C++ code(Algorithm), so how can i start? Can any one give me any type of tutorial or any related example link which will be help me to accomplish that task ? 
i haven't much knowledge of this type of task so what is good for me related that task please suggest me.

Comment: What system are you running on?

Comment: If your question is about C++, why did you tag this `C`?

Comment: @BjoernD it is for window base system

Comment: well, on "windows base system" 95 you could just open "COM1" as a dos file handle. or maybe tell us what system you are running on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Windows

```
HANDLE m_hParallelComm = CreateFile(portName,GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0,NULL); 

if(m_hParallelComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return false;

ReadFile( m_hParallelComm,data,  dwSize, &dwNumberOfBytesToRead, NULL);
CloseHandle(m_hParallelComm);
```

For read file function refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

A good article about [serial programming](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/serialcommunications/article.php/c5425/Serial-Communication-in-Windows.htm)

Comment: cant he use outp(int port_adr,int byte_value);  ?

Comment: @tuğrul büyükışık Not if you're running on top of an OS in protected mode. It'll also not work if the com port is an USB serial port.